# How to resolve Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

as mentioned in title I'm trying to insert a data to a table from another table below here.

```
Insert into dbo.result (
resultdate,
examdate
)
Select 
ResultDate,
ExamDate
From dbo.examdata
```

But I'm getting the error like in the title.the data type of columns in `result` table for both the columns are `int` but in `examdata` both  columns are `date` data types and I don't want to change the data type of result table.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use format function to convert date to int

Comment: As you said the data type of the table dbo.result in which you want to insert the data from dbo.examdata is int for both the columns. So, it will give error definitely. To resolve the issue change the data type matching with date i.e., either date or datetime.

Comment: That's what I asked like how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
Insert into dbo.result (
resultdate,
examdate
)
Select 
CONVERT(INT,FORMAT(ResultDate,'yyyyMMdd')) as ResultDate,
CONVERT(INT,FORMAT(ExamDate,'yyyyMMdd')) as ExamDate
From dbo.examdata
```

Comment: Can we change the same in insert statement also?

Comment: I didn't get you but insert statement only contains column names.

Comment: @VasZ You should accept the answer as it helped you. It decides others to find the answer easily.